# Get id of a control inside a datalist inside another datalist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a datalist named `dlcompCategory` and inside it another datalist named `dlComp` and inside it another datalist named `dlitem` and inside it I have a radio button named `rbOption`:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlcompCategory" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DataList ID="dlComp" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DataList ID="dlitem" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbOption" runat="server"></asp:RadioButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and in code bind a list in the radiobutton. How can I get whether the radiobutton is checked or not in radiobutton `onclick` event in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you clarify _"in code a bind a list in the checkbox"_?

Comment: make a class for the checkbox and then use the jquery selector to get your checkbox and see if its checked or not